# Symfony2 validations (yml) ignored

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have my validation.yml set-up in my bundles Resources/config directory. I enabled the use of the validator in my config.yml:

```
framework:
    validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

Resources/config/validation.yml:

```
MyBundle\AppBundle\Handler\SearchModel:
    properties:
        search:
            - Length:
                min: 2
                max: 50
                minMessage: "Your string must be at least {{ limit }} characters long"
                maxMessage: "Your string cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long"
```

In my controller i'm doing:

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($searchModel);
```

I'm pretty sure (because I double checked) that property of the model to be validated is string(1) 1 char. (should be minimal 2!)

But a var_dump() of $errors is stating:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList)#327 (1) {
["violations":"Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
}
```

Thus, no errors are thrown. How can I solve this? I want the validator to work :)

**Update**

I got it to work (for now) with a work-around. I added a loadValidatorMetaData method to the (SearchModel) class to validate.

```
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $metadata
        ->addPropertyConstraint(
            'search',
            new Assert\Length(
                array('min' => 2, 'minMessage' => 'Error message.')
            )
        );
}
```

When checking $validator->validate($searchModel); it returns the error, thus validations are working. But not with the .yml file :(

Comment: Start with the example in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service.  Replace 'pretty sure' with absolutely sure by testing with a new instance of your search model.  It's possible the cache needs clearing.  And your validation file lives in a Symfony 2 bundle which is loaded in your AppKernel?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I retested it, cleared the cache for the right env. Also my validation.yml looks correct. Still nothing. Is it possible that it only works for models in the entity directory?

Comment: It will work for all objects.  Double check the fully qualified name.  Maybe a typo in the namespace?

Comment: MyBundle\AppBundle is a bit suspicious.  I would have expected MyProject\AppBundle

Comment: Are you sure MyBundle\AppBundle is the correct namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I setup a little test case and got no errors.  I added a NotBlank constraint and got an error when search was blank.

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Command\SearchModel:
properties:
    search:
        - Length:
            min: 2
            max: 5
            minMessage: "Your string must be at least {{ limit }} characters long"
            maxMessage: "Your string cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long"
        - NotBlank: ~
```

I then set my search to one char

```
class SearchModel
{
    public $search = 'a';
}
```

And it triggered the min length error.

I read through the Length docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html.  Sure seems like a zero length string should trigger an error.

In any event, add a NotBlank constraint and you should be good to go.

I checked the code:

```
namespace Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;

class LengthValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (null === $value || '' === $value) {
        return;
    }
```

So I guess this is what is known as an undocumented 'feature'.  A string length of zero is not considered to be less than min!  Be curious to see if there is a bug report on this.  But again, NotBlank will work.  You can always adjust the error message so the user will know the limits.

Comment: You used a public variable. I should test with that as well. I'm using private variables. Could that be the case?

Comment: Nope.  Reflection is used to access the private variables.  Your NonBlank should be working as long as you are sure the class name is correct.  Use dir(get_class($searchModel)) to confirm.